# Are there any stats on browser widths as opposed to monitor size?

Tags: responsive-design, browser

Our analytics across several sites are all showing a marked increase in 1440px+ monitor size, but has anyone seen any stats about what browser size people with large screen tend to use?

Do people really go full width, or are they using larger screens to multitask?

Also, does anyone know a reliable way to measure this in Google Analytics?

Comment: I want to draw attention to [this article](https://mozilla.github.io/meao/2018/01/24/browser-sizes/) as it has an actual chart on it showing data from a big site - though unfortunately it's MDN so the audience is heavily biased towards developers.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like it will help get you the data you need:

http://css-tricks.com/screen-resolution-notequalto-browser-window/

As for general stats: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220263/general-browser-display-statistics

Basically, you can get the window AND screen/monitor size with some work.

Comment: +1 for the CSS tricks article, its one of the best done studies on relevant available space. At least IMHO, I have thought so for a long time.

Answer (score 2):

Google Analytics now records a dimension called "Browser Size". It doesn't appear to be suggested by the UI anywhere, but it's available for use in e.g. custom reports, secondary dimensions, and custom segments.

[image: Google Analytics → Audience → Mobile → Overview → Secondary dimension: Browser Size]

A team at Mozilla has written guidance on [extracting this data to plot a histogram of browser widths](https://mozilla.github.io/meao/2018/01/24/browser-sizes/).

Comment: Most importantly, that Mozilla post shows the actual chart, with data from a site that gets more volume than most sites the average reader here has access to. Thanks!