# Are there stats about height of browser windows worldwide / by industry?

Tags: website-design, web-app, responsive-design, browser, statistics

I wonder because I'm working on the design of trade platform and found that a lot of moments need improvements due to the different viewports on different devices and so on. The platform does not need a scroll, so I decided to choose top 3 sizes of browser height that are 650 px, 974 px and full-size 1080 px but through the googling I did not found any statistics about browser viewports. Is there at least one?

It's different to previously asked questions because there are no answer about height of viewports.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Statistics or research on browser window size based on the display screen size](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/59747/statistics-or-research-on-browser-window-size-based-on-the-display-screen-size)

Comment: @Nash no, it does not. My problem is wider than description of responsive design principles. Actually I need to know the exact sizes of popular **viewport** sizes, not display

Comment: There are standards for width. Which are globally accepted. But, there is no standard height for the browser window. It's hard to define the top 3 sizes. Although, we can consider the browser window height by selecting the most commonly used smartphones. Eg. iPhone 8,  Samsung Galaxy S9, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I personally use this website call [statcounter](https://gs.statcounter.com/screen-resolution-stats/desktop/worldwide).

I find it quite useful to decide with the team what viewports we should support, what breakpoint we should take into account, and what's the smallest mobile display we should focus on when building mobile experiences.

You can also filter by country, region, and other interesting parameters.

Comment: Sorry, but there are statistics only about display resolutions, not viewport

Comment: I believe you can capture the resolution of the screen easily, but not the viewport size as there are an infinity of sizes. Here's what can influence the viewport size:

- Resolution

- If the browser is in full screen or not

- If the browser has toolbars that take screen estate

- If the browser has download or status bars in the bottom

- If the user makes the browser window smaller

- If the user makes it larger

- If the user opens Developer mode on the bottom

- Etc...


There are many resolutions but an infinity or viewports on desktop.

Comment: yes, you are right about that there are a lot of, but some analytics tools capture it on the opening the website, so we can track on which size of browser user opens the site. Basically the screen size and the viewport size are took from the same DOM parameter. However, I don't see any open statistics of it.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure a large supported range of browsers on which your web application will be correctly displayed you need to bear on mind that there are two main groups.

**Mobile devices**

There are a very large amount of mobile screen sizes out there, from phones to tablets. Although smartphones today have large touch screens, nice user interfaces, and are highly optimized for browsing the web I'd probably support more than 3 screen sizes.

**Desktop browsers**

It's easier to focus on certain resolutions due to the market is not so wide here, but the audience of websites may vary from users having the most professional monitor to those that still using older computers.

Anyway you can have a look at the [**W3Schools Statistics about Browser Display**](https://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_display.asp). They have data collected from log-files over many years that clearly shows the long term trends.

Comment: W3Schools Statistics does not provide sizes of **viewports**

Comment: That link shows visitors to their own site which is likely to be only web developers.